# Sum returns 0 on a money column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

When I run this query:

```
SELECT [id],[amount],sum(amount) as Total
  FROM transaction
    where id='035'
  group by id, amount
```

I get some results like

```
id          amount      Total
035         -55115.24   -55115.24
035         -2126.14    -2126.14
```

However when I try to get a total (for the `amount` column), using this query;

```
 select id, count(*) as howMany, sum(amount) as Total
from transaction
where id='035'
group by id
order by count(*) desc
```

I get these results.

```
id              howMany Total
035             2        0.00
```

I would expect to get

```
id              howMany Total
035             2        -057241.38
```

I have tried to simplify the query, without the count, just to check if the sum is working

```
select id, sum(amount) as Total
from transaction
where id='035'
group by id
```

But again this gives me 0 as my total

```
id     Total
035     0.00
```

I have also tried this on id's that have positive values in their amount column but get the same behavior.

To clarify, I would like the total of the values in the `amount` column for each `id`, in the whole table, not just each row, but I only get zeroes when using the `SUM` function in SQL.

Another thing I noticed, the `id` column is an `nvarchar`, not the ID/key for the table. It is an old database which favors just linking nvarchars over primary keys, for some reason. I cannot change the table structure.

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transaction](
    [trindex] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [amount] [money] NULL,
    [acct] [varchar](20) NULL
)
```

Comment: Are you running this query in SQL Server Management Studio or through an application?  My first guess is that an application is changing the value.

Comment: I am running this through SSMS. The application won't be changing these values

Comment: What do you get from a simple sql:
SELECT [id],[amount]
  FROM transaction
    where id='035'

and what datatype is amount?

Comment: post the table schema. What data types are these really?

Comment: @SAS I get the id and the amounts, same as the first query in my post without the total column

Comment: OK but what is the datatype of Amount?

Comment: I've included the schema. Amount is `money`

Comment: What is the result if you run SELECT SUM(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(18,6))) FROM TRANSACTION WHERE id='035' ?

Comment: @DVT I had to add an extra bracket or it gave me a syntax error. Result was `0.00`. If I drop the `sum`, then I see the amounts as I did in my first query.

Comment: Can not replicate, I get 035 -57241,38

Comment: Is it anything to do with the DB running on SQL 2005? Perhaps SUM is behaving differently for me? I am running the queries via SSMS 2012 however.

Comment: could be 2005 I guess, try to convert to numeric before doing the sum:

select id, SUM(amount), SUM(convert(numeric(18,2), amount))

Comment: @JeffUK had to include a group by (ID) or an error occurs, I get one row with the ID and `0.00`

Comment: That gives me the same results as the first query

Comment: could be 2005 I guess, try to convert to numeric before doing the sum: select id, SUM(amount), SUM(convert(numeric(18,2), amount))

Comment: Do you have any records (meeting your `WHERE` criteria) with a `NULL` value in your `amount` column?

Comment: But rowcount is 2

Comment: Convert to numeric worked! That's really weird. Thanks @SAS - you can post it as an answer if you want?

Comment: Nice! Thank's for the update!

Comment: Thanks to everyone else for their help as well. Really strange one this. It's a pretty old application and the database does weird things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert to numeric before doing the sum: select id, SUM(amount), SUM(convert(numeric(18,2), amount))

Comment: I'd be very interested to know in what circumstances this is required.  If you give sum() an invalid data type you should get the error "Operand data type $foo is invalid for sum operator."

Comment: Money is not an exact datatype, but still, I agree.. I get the correct sum in 2012 though.

Comment: I think it is exact, but +- 55000 is a lot more than inexact

Comment: AFAIK, money datatype can introduce roundoff error into calculations (not on additions though). Also this was a big 'roundoff'.. but it's solved now.

Comment: I'd also be interested to know what's going on here :) Very strange one. I don't get why casting to numeric works but casting to anything else gives me zero. This database is linked to a very old system though and has been known to have odd behaviour previously.

Comment: Exactly, me too, I could not duplicate the error or google a solution, so the workaround converting to another datatype was the best I could think of, given your situation.